# Time complexity of Euler totient function?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

To calculate $\phi(n)$, I iterate $k=1$ to $n$ and count how many times $gcd(k,n)=1$.

Would the runtime of the function still be considered $O(n)$? Or would it be $O(n log n)$ due to the gcd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be $O(n\log n)$ due to the time it takes to compute each gcd.

I believe it would be faster to factor $n$ and then use [Euler's product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_product_formula) for $\phi(n)$. Known factoring algorithms are still slow for large numbers $n$, but they do run much faster than $O(n)$. (Even trial division is $O(\sqrt n)$.)

Comment: A tricky extension to the question could ask if the bound $O(n\log n)$ is tight (in the sense of being $\Theta(n\log n)$). I have a feeling it might not be so.

Comment: Certainly not. Using trial division to factor $n$ and then multiplying out the Euler product formula certainly gives at most $n^{1/2+\varepsilon}$, and more modern factorization algorithms give $n^\epsilon$.

Comment: I didn't refer to the *optimal* algorithm for this problem; but rather to the one proposed by the original poster. I.e. how fast does the sum of number of operations required to compute $\gcd(n,k)$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ grow?

Comment: Ah, I see. I imagine that question is answered somewhere in the literature, though I'm not sure. I share your instinct that one can do better than $O(n\log n)$.